# I set a property in my custom controller wrapper in OnActionExecuting, how to pass to Site.Master?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a class that wraps the Controller class:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;}

    public override void OnActionExecuting(...) 
    {
          SomeProperty = "hello";
    }

}
```

Now in my site.master, I want to have access to the **SomeProperty** that I just set.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each view `<%= ViewContext.Controller %>` will give you the instance of the controller that rendered this view. If you have a base controller for all actions and the property is on this base controller you could cast and access the property. Writing a helper method to do this might be even better:

```
<%= Html.SomeProperty() %>
```

with the following helper defined:

```
public static MvcHtmlString SomeProperty(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    var controller = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller as BaseController;
    if (controller == null)
    {
        // The controller that rendered this view was not of type BaseController
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlHelper.Encode(controller.SomeProperty));
}
```

Comment: Controller Properties as ViewData? How could you recommend this? Crazy!

Comment: I agree with jfar, this is crazy!

Comment: I never said that I recommend this. I just answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

If the ViewData.Model type is known you can set it via:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var myModel = ((ViewResult) filterContext.Result).ViewData.Model as ProfessionalMembership;
    myModel.SomeProperty = "hello";

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Now SomeProperty will be populated in your View's Model.

If you don't know the model type you can always use the ViewData dictionary.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    ((ViewResult) filterContext.Result).ViewData["Propery"] = "asdf";

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```